# system restart through None Admin User account

Tags: c#

hi i want to restart my system through one code that is running through none admin account but its not working.kindly help me.

here is the code

```
    try
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm").Equals("4:00"))

            {

                ProcessStartInfo Autorestart = new                           ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Autostart.bat");
                Autorestart.UseShellExecute = false;

                SecureString pw = new SecureString();

                pw.AppendChar('p');
                pw.AppendChar('a');
                pw.AppendChar('s');
                pw.AppendChar('s');
                pw.AppendChar('w');
                pw.AppendChar('o');
                pw.AppendChar('r');
                pw.AppendChar('d');

                Autorestart.Password = pw;
                Autorestart.UserName = "support";
```

Comment: what's actually is not working? if you can share error/stack trace if there's any that would help resolving issue.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted that would trigger a restart. If you trigger the restart in the .bat file you should add it's content to your question.

Comment: yes sir here is .bat file
%windir%\system32\shutdown -r -t 00

Comment: actually it is not being restart

Comment: Can't you use the task scheduler for this?

Comment: where did you actually start your process? (new Process(Autorestart)).Start(); or simply Process.Start("file name", "arguments");

Answer (score 0):

In your Autostart.bat just add this.

shutdown -r -t 05;

I hope it helps.

Comment: That would work too, but I don't see why he's trying to execute a batch script from C#, why not just restart the system from your code (albeit with usage of CMD)?

Comment: i used the above mentioned code but its not giving the result.as i told that i want to restart from none admin account.can any body help me to sort it out plzzzzzzzzz

Comment: if (DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm").Equals("4:00"))
                
                { System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "shutdown /t");

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to ask why you want to write code that restarts at 4:00, but I will help ;-). The restart function in C# requires admin rights as it can be used maliciously, but to do this as a woraround, you just need to add `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "shutdown /r");`. This uses a command prompt command to restart (the `/r` switch). See below for the final code:

```
if (DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") == "04:00")
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "shutdown /r /t {time in seconds}")
```

I have no idea why you want to do this, or why you have all that code for secure passwords and usernames and string building and everything else, but this is the easiest way.

Comment: yes sir the support user is administrator rights user

Comment: @abid Just stick the process call in your code where you want to shut down, and your code should then restart the PC. Be warned though, the shutdown command usually has a delay. To remove this use `-t {time in seconds}`. The default is 20 seconds.

Comment: @abid It's a switch, so add it after the `/r`. Apologies, I meant `/t {time in seconds}`

Comment: @abid and then remove all references to your batch script. C# doesn't rely on batch scripts to work. Anything you can do in command prompt scripts, you can do in C#. The same goes for VisualBasic scripts.

Comment: CMD.EXE does not know the argument 'shutdown'. I think you forgot the /K flag or similar?

Comment: @Anonymouse
sir please give me the proper code as you are telling.please.i am not so expert person.please help me with the whole set of code.plzzzzzzz

Comment: @abid Please see the code above. Also, please at least try and use the code when you next ask a question, we love to help but don't love to do it for you :-)